# How to invoke POCO's PageCompiler?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, poco-libraries

I feel stupid.

https://pocoproject.org/pro/docs/PageCompilerUserGuide.html

It says:

```
Invoking the Page Compiler

The Page Compiler is invoked from the command line. The file names of the CPSP files to be compiled are specified as arguments.

A number of options control the code generation. Options are specified using the usual command-line option syntax for the current operating system (e.g., <[/help on Windows, <[--help or <[-h on Unix).

    help (h): display usage information
    define (D): define a configuration property
    config-file (f): load configuration properties from a file
    osp (O): add factory class definition/implementation for use with OSP
    apache (A): add factory class definition/implementation and shared library manifest for use with ApacheConnector
    escape (e): make HTML-escape mode default for all pages

Run the PageCompiler with the —help option to see all available options.
```

Ok, cool. But what/where is the actual executable? I have all POCO libs installed on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` from the default repository.

POCO seems to be great library, but I find the documentation (not only this) severely lacking. Mainly due to non-existent examples.

Answer (score 2):

I installed and built POCO from source.
PageCompiler is in Poco-x.x.x.x-all/PageCompiler/bin/Linux/x86_64.
It is called **cpspc** and **cpspcd**.
When installed it is copyed in **/usr/local/bin/**, in the path.
Done on Fedora 31.

Comment: Hmm...for some reason that doesn't exist on Ubuntu when all POCO stuff is installed and I don't see any tools package either. Maybe it requires a newer version..

Comment: Did you also build it?

Comment: BTW, It looks like there is a package for this named "poco-cpspc" if you don't want to compile it.  I haven't tried it but `sudo apt-get install poco-cpspc` might get you what you need.

Comment: No, I didn't build it. Hmm...there's no such package available on `Ubuntu 18.04`. In which repository is that?